# Include complete documents as appendix

Tags: appendices

I have a document `main.tex` that has a title, toc, references, and lastly that document should include a couple of documents that were previously written in LaTeX with their own titlepage, toc, and references: `A.tex`, `B.tex`.

I want my structure to be:

```
Main
  TOC
  Section 1
    Subsection 1.1

  References
Appendix A
  TOC (for Appendix A)
  Section A.1
    Subsection A.1.1
  References for Appendix A
Appendix B
  TOC
  Section...
  Refs for AppB...
App C....
  ....
```

Normal `\include`/`\input` seem not to work for me. Is there any way to accomplish this?

EDiT MWE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/favrw6vr37ft1xa/tex.rar?dl=0

Comment: You might want to compile them and include them with `pdfpages` - searching that term here or on google should give you some useful hints.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: could you explain why "normal \include/\input" is not working for you? Because in principle they should, so I'm wondering what feature you require that you don't think you can have when using `\input`

Comment: @sheß I don't know, http://pastebin.com/raw/QvxtQL5r
I have titlepage, toc and references in the included file but don't see any errors linked to that.

Comment: Okay, with the parts that you show us it is a bit difficult to figure out what's going on. Best you go with the suggested pdfpages solution, or you should give us some more detailed code (minimal examples) that we can compile to see where your issue with `\input` lies

Comment: you might have to use partial tocs/refs when you want to typeset it all together

Comment: @sheß MWE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/favrw6vr37ft1xa/tex.rar?dl=0

That is sort of what I would like to produce.

Answer (score 2):

In case your preferred output format is pdf have a look at the **`pdfpages`** package. It provides the macro `\includepdf`.

Comment: This has been proposed already in comments

Comment: This answer appeared at about the same time as the similar comments, so I think it's ok.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I appreciate every answer, even if it simply repeats a comment, because you can accept an answer and make the question disappear from the list of unanswered questions. Currently there are more than 9000 question marked as unanswered, although many of them have been answered in a comment. Why do you propose a bloated list of 'unanswered' questions?